# Simplifying Boolean Function with Karnaugh Map

Tags: boolean-algebra

[image]

How to write Product-of-sum(POS) and Sum-of-product(SOP) Above K-Map?

I already write POS please check my answer.

Comment: You can convince yourself that your expression is wrong. ABCD should be 1 but is not according to your result.

Answer (score 0):

The original expression

```
(!a or !b or !d) and (!b or !c or !d) and (!a or !b or !c) and (!a or !c or !d)
```

translates to a sum of six minterms

```
!a!b + !a!c + !b!c + !a!d + !b!d + !c!d

             ab
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   01 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
cd    +---+---+---+---+
   11 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   10 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

The entries of the Karnaugh map are inverse to the diagrams in the question.